# How do I refer to multiple nesting levels in an Elastic Search's Filter Aggregation?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elassandra

Let's call my root level `foo` and my child level `events`. I want to aggregate on the `events` level but with a filter that EITHER the `event` has color "orange" OR the parent `foo` has customerId "35".

So, I want to have a filter aggregation that's inside a nested aggregation. In this filter's query clause, I have one child that refers to a field on `foo` and the other refers to a field on `events`. However, that first child has no way to actually reference the parent like that! I can't use a reverse_nested aggregation because I can't put one of those as a child of a compound query, and I can't filter before nesting because I'd lose the OR semantics that way. How do I reference the field on `foo`?

Concrete example if it helps. Mapping:

```
{
  "foo": {
    "properties": {
      "customer_id": { "type": "long" },
      "events": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "color": { "type": "keyword" },
          "coord_y": { "type": "double" }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

(update for clarity: that's an index named `foo` with the root mapping named `foo`)

The query I want to be able to make:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "OP0_nest": {
      "nested": { "path": "events" },
      "aggs": {
        "OP0_custom_filter": {
          "filter": {
            "bool": {
              "should": [
                { "term": { "events.color": "orange" } },
                { "term": { "customer_id": 35 } }
              ]
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "OP0_op": {
              "avg": { "field": "events.coord_y" }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Of course, this does not work, because the child of the `should` clause containing `customer_id` does not work. That term query is always false because `customer_id` can't be accessed inside the nested aggregation.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Since the fields you want to apply filter on are at different levels you need to make query for each level separately and place them in `should` clause of `bool` query which becomes the `filter` for our filter aggregation. In this aggregation we then add a nested aggregation to get the avg of `coord_y`.

The aggregation will be (**UPDATED**: since `foo` is index name removed `foo` from field names):

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "OP0_custom_filter": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "term": {
                "customer_id": 35
              }
            },
            {
              "nested": {
                "path": "events",
                "query": {
                  "term": {
                    "events.color": "orange"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "OP0_op": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "events"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "OP0_op_avg": {
              "avg": {
                "field": "events.coord_y"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: right, but now you're filtering `foo` rather than filtering `events`. so we'll still be averaging the coord_y for events that are neither orange nor belonging to customer with ID 35 with this query, right?

Comment: Okay so I've tested this and my theory was right. What this query is doing is saying, filter `foo` down to a bucket of `foo` docs that either are for customer ID 35 or have any orange child `events` doc. But, the problem with that is, once I nest to the `events` level that filtering isn't respected anymore. The filtering needs to occur after I've nested to the `events` level but I specifically CANT filter anymore once I've nested to the `events` level.

Comment: Also, have I made a mistake in my example? The `foo` is just the name of the index, `foo` itself is not nested within anything.

Comment: *once I nest to the events level that filtering isn't respected anymore. The filtering needs to occur after I've nested to the events level but I specifically CANT filter anymore once I've nested to the events level.*

How does this differ in expected result?

Comment: It differs in that my expected result is that I only get events that either have color = orange, or whose parent foo has customerid = 35. Your query will still aggregate events that have neither color = orange nor whose parent foo has customerid = 35. It aggregates events that either have parent foo customer = 35 OR parent foo with ANY child events with color = orange.

Comment: It's `should` not `must_not`. How come my query aggregate neither - nor I wonder.